# Converting LANDSAT-8 TIFF to matrix, data frame, or SpatialGridDataFrame formates

Tags: r, convert, landsat, file-formats, normalize

I need to correct the reflectance values of LANDSAT-8 data for steep terrain and find it too tedious and clunky in ArcGIS. The data I have is:
LANSDAT-8
DEM (ASTER)
Slope and aspect (Derived using DEM in ArcGIS)
Sun Elevation and Azimuth (Obtained from L8 MTL file)

All of which are clipped to a polygon of my study area.

Two methods I wanted to use were the cosine and minneart corrections. I found a package for R called "landsat" - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/landsat/index.html thatcontains a function named "topocorr" - http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/landsat/docs/topocorr which takes the uncorrected image, slope, aspect, azimuth and elevation then produces a corrected image.

I'm struggling to use it however as the input data type for the input image is "matrix, data frame, or SpatialGridDataFrame" formats.

How can I convert L8 data into this format?

Comment: Read it it with the readGDAL function in the rgdal package, which returns a SpatialGridDataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @mdsumner, You can read a SpatialGridDataFrame directly using readGDAL in the rgdal package. You can also easily coerce raster objects to a SpatialGridDataFrame or matrix. If your imagery is in separate files I would recommend reading them in as a stack and then coercing to a SpatialGridDataFrame.

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)

# Using readGDAL to read raster (if in multi-band stack format) 
y = readGDAL(system.file("pictures/Rlogo.jpg", package = "rgdal")[1])
  head(y@data)

# Using raster to create stack from individual bands and coerce to SpatialGridDataFrame
y <- stack( raster(system.file("pictures/Rlogo.jpg", package = "rgdal")[1], band=1),
            raster(system.file("pictures/Rlogo.jpg", package = "rgdal")[1], band=2),
            raster(system.file("pictures/Rlogo.jpg", package = "rgdal")[1], band=3))
class(y)

y <- as(y, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
  class(y)

# do something to the data and write raster to disk  
y@data <- y@data * 0.01  
writeGDAL(y, "corrected.tif", drivername="GTiff", type="Float32")
```

Answer (score -1):

install raster package, then load band by band. Then you can use landsat package. Ex:

```
library(raster)
setwd(L8 folder)
b1=raster("L8b1.tif")
b2=raster("L8b2.tif")
image=stack(b1,b2)
```

Comment: Reading a raster or stack object does not result in a SpatialGridDataFrame object. You can coerce to a sp or matrix class object but your current solution does not provide this information.